# Select multiple entities in Criteria Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In NHibernate HQL you can select multiple entities for a given query like this example.

```
var query = session.CreateQuery("select c,k from Cat as c join c.Kittens as k");
```

Obviously the real world situation has more complexity but that is the basics.  Is there a way to do this in a Criteria query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOIN FETCH.

HQL would be this -

```
FROM Cat C JOIN FETCH C.Kittens
```

Answer (score 0):

var catsWithKittens = session.createCriteria()
    .SetFetchmode("Kittens", Fetchmode.Eager)
    .List();